# Checksum validation failed in maven due to PART files with Java 11

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3

## Background

I am using Java 11.0.3, Maven 3.6.2 and com.github.seahen.maven-s3-wagon 1.3.1.

I am using an s3 bucket as a maven repository. I have an internal jar artifact called *dbclasses*.  I deploy *dbclasses* to the s3 maven repository using `mvn source:jar deploy`.

I have a different maven project called *secapps* which uses the *dbclasses* artifact.  Here is the relevant configuration related to the s3 bucket and the artifact in the *secapps* pom file

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.nuvalence.repo.release</id>
        <url>s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.nuvalence.repo.snapshot</id>
        <url>s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.github.seahen</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.excelsior</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbclasses</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Issue

Whenever I run a `mvn clean package` on secapps it throws the following warning

```
[INFO] Downloading from maven.nuvalence.repo.release: s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom
[INFO] Logged in - ec-appdev-mvn-repo
[INFO] Downloading: s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom
[INFO] Downloading: s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom.sha1
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected  but is 38790b95f185a41908a1767ae2ad2b5bfe436773 from maven.nuvalence.repo.release for s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom
[INFO] Downloading: s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom
[INFO] Downloading: s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom.sha1
[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom: Checksum validation failed, expected  but is 38790b95f185a41908a1767ae2ad2b5bfe436773
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected  but is 38790b95f185a41908a1767ae2ad2b5bfe436773 from maven.nuvalence.repo.release for s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from maven.nuvalence.repo.release: s3://ec-appdev-mvn-repo/release/edu/excelsior/dbclasses/0.0.1/dbclasses-0.0.1.pom (4.7 kB at 2.8 kB/s)
[INFO] Logged off - ec-appdev-mvn-repo
```

You'll notice that it says **Checksum validation failed, expected  but is 38790b95f185a41908a1767ae2ad2b5bfe436773**

In other words, the expected checksum is 38790b95f185a41908a1767ae2ad2b5bfe436773, but you've given me **blank**.

So I looked at the local repository and I see the following

[image: local repo]

You'll notice the following two things for each file

- For the pom and jar files there is an associated .part file
- the .part file contains all the data, but the non the actual files are empty

If the .part files are renamed to remove the .partXXXX everything works fine.  But for some reason every time I try to build it keeps the .part files and leaves the normal files at 0K

## Question

What are these .part files and why are my normal files 0K?  How do I resolve this?

## Attempts

I have tried many things including

- Manually deleting the dependency from my local repository
- Redeploying the dependency to s3
- Setting checksumPolicy to warning
- Setting updatePolicy to always

However, none of these seem to work. Does anyone have a solution for this?  All the other dependencies from Maven central pull down fine.  None of the dependencies form s3 work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the latest version of seahen s3 wagon 1.3.3 because the previous versions of seahen wagon doesn't work properly with newest java versions. And also you need to add the suitable dependency to work that wagon properly.
Add following wagon and dependency to *pom.xml*, delete all the previous builds in *m2* as well as *github* file in *m2* and try to reload project. That will resolve issue.

**Wagon**

```
<extension>
    <groupId>com.github.seahen</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</extension>
```

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.seahen</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

For further reference follow these links

https://github.com/seahen/maven-s3-wagonhttps://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.seahen/maven-s3-wagon/1.3.3

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

It looks like maven-s3-wagon doesn't play well with Java 11.  I swapped out the maven-s3-wagon wagon for the aws-maven wagon and it resolved my issue

**Prior wagon**

```
<extension>
    <groupId>com.github.seahen</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</extension>
```

**New Wagon**

```
<extension>
    <groupId>com.github.platform-team</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</extension>
```

Comment: I also tried with aws-maven wagon. But it didn't work in all scenarios. It download the artifacts but in some cases .jar was missing. And that didn't complete the download from s3